# Regex group matching in Java

Tags: regex

I m trying to use regex to match the following string

```
[one[two[three[four|five]|six|seven]
```

I wanted them in three groups

`[one[two[three` , `[four|five]` ,`|six|seven]`

This is what i have come up with so far

```
(\\].*) for  |six|seven] and `(\\[.*\\[)` for [one[two[three
```

and I m finding it difficult to match the last group which is `[four|five]`

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the import:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

If the number of elements does not change (as you did not specified), you can use the following:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[.+\\[.+)(\\[.+\\|.+])(\\|.+\\|.+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[one[two[three[four|five]|six|seven]");

    //execute matching (required to iterate over groups)
    boolean matched = matcher.matches();

    for(int i=0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
```

`\` regex escapers are escaped, so that Java does not use them as escapers instead of letting them to the regex tool. I used the `\` escapers because you want to match literal `|`, not interpreting them as `or` operator.

`.` Matches every character except line terminators.